# How to query RethinkDB based on the current time

Tags: python, rethinkdb

I'm trying to write a 'controller' program for a RethinkDB database which continuously dumps to JSON and deletes data which is older than 3 days, using RethinkDB's changefeed feature.

The problem is that the query 'hangs' from the current time, which is evaluated using `datetime.utcnow()` (or, alternatively, `rethinkdb.now()`) at the time the query is defined, remaining fixed thereafter. So as the changefeed progresses, the query becomes 'outdated'.

How can I make a query which is continuously 'updated' to reflect the current time?

To illustrate the problem, here is the script so far:

```
import json
import rethinkdb as r
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# The database and table are assumed to have been previously created
database_name = "sensor_db"
table_name = "sensor_data"
table = r.db(database_name).table(table_name)

port_offset = 1         # To avoid interference of this testing program with the main program, all ports are initialized at an offset of 1 from the default ports using "rethinkdb --port_offset 1" at the command line.
conn = r.connect("localhost", 28015 + port_offset)

current_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)   # Current time including timezone (assumed to be UTC)
retention_period = timedelta(days=3)                        # Period of time during which data is retained on the main server
expiry_time = current_time - retention_period               # Age at which data is removed from the main database

if "timestamp" in table.index_list().run(conn):         # Assuming the table has "timestamp" as a secondary index, use "between" (for improved speed)
    beginning_of_time = r.time(1400, 1, 1, 'Z')    # The minimum time of a ReQL time object (the year 1400)
    data_to_archive = table.between(beginning_of_time, expiry_time, index="timestamp")
else:     # Else, use "filter" (requires more memory, but does not require "timestamp" to be a secondary index)
    data_to_archive = table.filter(r.row['timestamp'] < expiry_time)

output_file = "archived_sensor_data.json"
with open(output_file, 'a') as f:
    for change in data_to_archive.changes().run(conn, time_format="raw"):        # The time_format="raw" option is passed to prevent a "RqlTzinfo object is not JSON serializable" error when dumping
        if change['new_val'] is not None:               # If the change is not a deletion
            print change
            json.dump(change['new_val'], f)             # Since the main database we are reading from is append-only, the 'old_val' of the change is always None and we are interested in the 'new_val' only
            f.write("\n")                               # Separate entries by a new line
            ID_to_delete = change['new_val']['id']                # Get the ID of the data to be deleted from the database
            r.db(database_name).table(table_name).get(ID_to_delete).delete().run(conn)
```

The query is stored in the variable `data_to_archive`. However, the time interval in the `between` statement is based on the `utcnow()` when the `current_time` variable is defined, and is not continuously updated in the changefeed. How could I make it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked around the problem by doing the dumps in 'batch' mode rather than continuously using `changes()`. (To wit, I'm using the [schedule](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) module).

Here is the script:

```
import json
import rethinkdb as r
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import schedule
import time
import functools

def generate_archiving_query(retention_period=timedelta(days=3), database_name="ipercron", table_name="sensor_data", conn=None):
    if conn is None:
        conn = r.connect("localhost", 28015)

    table = r.db(database_name).table(table_name)               # RethinkDB cursor for the table of interest
    current_time = r.now()
    expiry_time = current_time - retention_period.total_seconds()

    if "timestamp" in table.index_list().run(conn):         # If the table has "timestamp" as a secondary index, use "between" (for improved speed)
        beginning_of_time = r.time(1400, 1, 1, 'Z')         # The minimum time of a ReQL time object (the year 1400)
        data_to_archive = table.between(beginning_of_time, expiry_time, index="timestamp")
    else:                                                   # Else, use "filter" (requires more memory, but does not require "timestamp" to be a secondary index)
        data_to_archive = table.filter(r.row['timestamp'] < expiry_time)

    # try:
    #     beginning_of_time = r.time(1400, 1, 1, 'Z')         # The minimum time of a ReQL time object (the year 1400)
    #     data_to_archive = table.between(beginning_of_time, expiry_time, index="timestamp")
    # except:
    #     data_to_archive = table.filter(r.row['timestamp'] < expiry_time)

    return data_to_archive

def archiving_job(data_to_archive=None, output_file="archived_sensor_data.json", database_name="ipercron", table_name="sensor_data", conn=None):
    if data_to_archive is None:
        data_to_archive = generate_archiving_query()
    if conn is None:
        conn = r.connect("localhost", 28015)

    table = r.db(database_name).table(table_name)
    old_data = data_to_archive.run(conn, time_format="raw")         # Without time_format="raw" the output does not dump to JSON
    with open(output_file, 'a') as f:
        ids_to_delete = []
        for item in old_data:
            print item
            json.dump(item, f)
            f.write('\n')                                           # Separate each document by a new line
            ids_to_delete.append(item['id'])
            # table.get(item['id']).delete().run(conn)

    table.get_all(r.args(ids_to_delete)).delete().run(conn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # The database and table are assumed to have been previously created
    database_name = "ipercron"
    table_name = "sensor_data"
    # table = r.db(database_name).table(table_name)

    port_offset = 1         # To avoid interference of this testing program with the main program, all ports are initialized at an offset of 1 from the default ports using "rethinkdb --port_offset 1" at the command line.
    conn = r.connect("localhost", 28015 + port_offset)

    clean_slate = True
    if clean_slate:
        r.db(database_name).table(table_name).delete().run(conn)            # For testing, start with an empty table and add a fixed amount of data
        import rethinkdb_add_data

    data_to_archive = generate_archiving_query(conn=conn, database_name=database_name, table_name=table_name)        # Because r.now() is evaluated upon run(), the query needs only to be generated once
    archiving_job_fixed_query = functools.partial(archiving_job, data_to_archive=data_to_archive, conn=conn)

    schedule.every(0.1).minutes.do(archiving_job_fixed_query)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a predicate(lambda) function written in ReQL

Your python sets the present time as that at the time of the python execution (which occurs once). Then, when sent to the RethinkDB server that is a hardcoded timestamp.

By using the predicate function the RDB server should continuously evaluate the predicate against all relevant records using the present time as the time of evaluation on the RethinkDB server

table.filter(lambda (row) {row['timestamp'] < r.now()}).changes()

I am thinking of doing this for my own use case but am worried about the load this type of query would place on the server. If you try this let us know how it goes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).